# Maps for commercial WPF applications

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, google-maps, bing-maps

I'm currently developping a commercial Windows application (closed-source, free demo with limited functionality available) in .Net 4.0 using C# and WPF. I'm now looking for a map library with the following features:

- World-wide online map and/or satellite data (Like Bing or Google Maps. Due to lack of coverage however, OpenStreetMap does not qualify)
- Display of custom colored placemarks
- Optionally: Possibility to easily add a simplified offline map, on a lower zoom level

Which mapping solution satisfy those requirements without violating any licenses of the map provider?

Comment: Those are very strict requirements that are likely only to be satisfied by purchasing licenses from Google or Microsoft.

Comment: Why is OSM excluded, it would give you all for free?

Comment: @Damokles: The map coverage of OSM is very poor for most regions outside Europe or the US. It's a fascinating project though.

Comment: Why is Bing maps excluded? I've seen it in action (haven't coded myself though), and with minimal lines of code, you can show a map in you application. I'm asking because I will be in a similar position some time.

Comment: Bing isn't excluded. I've amended the question. How did you implement the map in your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at NASA World Wind?  They have a lot of developer information hosted on their website.  It is JAVA based, but there are ways around that.

http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/

And being a Government Agency, I would image that their imagery is Free-Use.

[**ESRI website  Developer Tools Product Page**](http://www.esri.com/products/index.html#developer_tools_panel)

Comment: Yes, the data source seems to be (mostly) free to use, but the software itself (World Wind) doesn't seem to be aviable as plugin for other applications.

Comment: If you could elaborate on why it is not a good fit, it would help in finding a better one...

Comment: Well, according to the World Wind forums, it is not possible to host the World Wind software in a WPF application. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I have seen instances of Java content hosted in a WPF application, but I cannot speak to their performance.  If you have money, you could buy a license for ArcGIS and use Arc's COM libraries to pull WMS data from Google or Bing (again I have seen this done, but have not had direct experience).  ArcGIS is a pretty heady software, and will require some study to get it working the way you want though.  Hell people go to colleges to to learn how to use it effectively.  I'll add a link to ESRI to post above.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll have a look and a chat with our GIS people then.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd choose Bing, it is fairly simple. As I said, I haven't done it myself, but I've seen it on a demo. It should be something like:

```
<maps:Map Name="bingmap" Mode="AerialWithLabels" CredentialsProvider="enteryourkeyhere"/>
```

Where maps is the namespace: `clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl`

Then, in code-behind:

```
GeoCoordinate co = new GeoCoordinate((double)myLatitude, (double)myLongitude);
bingmap.SetView(co, 18);
```

Courtesy goes to Kevin Derudder who did a great presentation (which is where I saw it). It was about Silverlight, but should be almost the same for WPF. Check out his [blog post](http://kevinderudder.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/building-desktop-applications-with-silverlight/), with code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to go commercial.  If so, also look at Thinkgeo Mapsuite.

Answer (score 0):

This is excellent, I guess it will have more than you need:
[Great Maps for Windows Forms & Presentation](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/)

Just download code and check out the demo!